# Delimiters and converting split to preg_split because of deprecation in PHP 5.3

Tags: php, deprecated

To convert split to preg_split due to the deprecation in PHP 5.3, you do:

```
$temp_array = split("\s*;\s*", $string);
$temp_array = preg_split("/\s*;\s*/", $string);
```

Note the delimiters "/" needed for preg_split.

```
$temp_array = split($needle, $string);
$temp_array = preg_split($needle, $string);
```

Does the "$needle" need the delimiters too?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `$needle` must be a regular expression if you're going to use `preg_split`. Regular expressions need delimiters.

If it's *not* a regular expression that you need to split by, use [`explode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

Comment: +1 ... Adding to this; to safely use `$needle` in `preg_split` you can write `preg_split('/' . preg_quote($needle, '/') . '/', $string)`

Comment: @Jack is right, but you should really use explode() for that since it's not actually a regular expression.

Comment: It's not clear from the question what `split` was used for, so it's just erring on the safe side. But you have already catered for the non-regex case in your answer, so we should have complete coverage :)